# A simpler TinyMCE hyperlink plugin

Tags: javascript, tinymce

TinyMCE has a hyperlink plug-in that allows you to select a piece of text, and wrap an <a> around it.

But it's a bit too obtrusive- it opens up a big new popup window, with many options for the user to pay attention, wait, think and configure.

Is there a simpler alternative to it? Something that does a basic job of inserting an anchor in a more subtle way (maybe just with a one-click simple javascript input prompt)?

Thanks,

Pradyumna

Answer (score 0):

Write it yourself, it is not that difficult. Take the hyperlink plugin rename it and strip everything that you think is not necessary.